# Run javascript after form submission in update panel?

Tags: .net, javascript, jquery, updatepanel, postback

This is driving me crazy! I have read at least 5 questions on here closely related to my problem, and probably 5 or so more pages just from googling. I just don't get it.

I am trying to have a jqueryui dialog come up after a user fills out a form saying 'registration submitted' and then redirecting to another page, but I cannot for the life of me get any javascript to work, not even a single alert.

Here is my update panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upForm" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
               'Rest of form'
         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" /> 
              <p>Did register Pass? <%= registrationComplete %></p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The Jquery I want to execute: (Right now this is sitting in the head of the markup, with autoOpen set to false)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function pageLoad() {

    $('#registerComplete').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 270,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
          "Ok": function() {
          window.location.href = "someUrl";
        }
        }
    });

}
     </script>
```

Finally my code behind: ( Commented out all the things I've tried)

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click     
      'Dim sbScript As New StringBuilder()'
           registrationComplete = True
            registrationUpdatePanel.Update()

            'sbScript.Append("<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>" + ControlChars.Lf)'
            'sbScript.Append("<!--" + ControlChars.Lf)'
            'sbScript.Append("window.location.reload()" + ControlChars.Lf)'
            'sbScript.Append("// -->" + ControlChars.Lf)'
            'sbScript.Append("</")'
            'sbScript.Append("script>" + ControlChars.Lf)'

            'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "AutoPostBack", sbScript.ToString(), False)'
            'ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("AutoPostBackScript", sbScript.ToString())'
                            'Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Test')</script>")'
            'Response.Write("<script>windows.location.reload()</script>")'
End Sub
```

I've tried:

- Passing variables from server to
  client via inline <%= %> in the
  javascript block of the head tag.
- Putting that same code in a script
  tag inside the updatePanel.
- Tried to use
  RegisterClientScriptBlock and
  RegisterStartUpScript
- Just doing a Response.Write with the 
  script tag written in it.
- Tried various combinations of putting
  the entire jquery.dialog code in the 
  registerstartup script, or just
  trying to change the autoOpen
  property, or just calling "open" on
  it.

I can't even get a simple alert to work with any of these, so I am doing something wrong but I just don't know what it is.

Here is what I know:

- The Jquery is binding properly even
  on async postbacks, because the div
  container that is the dialog box is
  always invisible, I saw a similiar
  post on here stating that was causing
  an issue, this isn't the case here.
- Using page_load instead of
  document.ready since that is supposed
  to run on both async and normal
  postbacks, so that isn't the issue.
- The update panel is updating
  correctly because `<p>Did register
  Pass? <%= registrationComplete
  %></p>` updates to true after I
  submit the form.

So how can I make this work? All I want is -> click submit button inside an update panel -> run server side code to validate form and insert into db -> if everything succeeded, have that jquery (modal) dialog pop up saying hey it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register from the Codebehind, [here's the format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hab26949(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "AutoPostBackScript", 
                                   "alert('hi');", True);
```

The `true` on the end tells it to wrap your code in `<script>` tags, leave it off if you want to do the tags yourself.

Comment: @Nick: Not sure why but registering javascript on async postbacks never worked to me unless I use as parameter the type of the update panel (UpdatePanel1.GetType())

Comment: @Claudio - Depends where it's being called from, should be called from a control that's participating in the update, the update panel itself isn't a bad type to stick it on, so yes that works :)

Comment: you should be using `ScriptManager` instead of `ClientScript` for pages with `UpdatePanels`.

Comment: @Nick Craver, you can't just call GetType()

Comment: @AverageJoe719 - Sure you can - It's `Page.GetType()` that you're calling, just like you don't need to call `Page.Response.End()`, it's just `Response.End()`.

Comment: @Nick Craver, that's odd, When I tried doing that, it gave me an error, so I just typed Page.GetType() as you said and that worked. Using VB not sure if that mattered. But I figured it out and it works with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, myUpdatePanel.GetType(), "AutoPostBackScript", "alert('Hi');", True)` Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and I had to use `ScriptManager` instead of `ClientScript`, and I had to pass the `UpdatePanel` and its type. `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(mycontrol, mycontrol.GetType(), "callback", "alert('ho')", true);`

Answer (score 3):

You may checkout the [endRequest event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx):

```
function pageLoad() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, e) {
        // this function will be executed after the update panel finished 
        // the AJAX request, so here you may open your jQuery dialog

        if (e.get_error()) {

        } else {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So how would I pass it a variable like I did above? The problem I ran into is that the variable I pass in <%= %> only runs once when the page is loaded. Any subsequent async postbacks might run that code, but it wouldn't update to the newest value of registrationComplete. What is E in your example? The page? So in your example I would have a get_error() function in the code behind and it would work? Or would that be in the Javascript? If in the Javascript, I still run into the issue of giving it the updated value.